# Explain mysterious class name in XStream XML stream

Tags: xstream

I'm using XStream 1.4.8 to serialize to and from XML, when sending data through RabbitMQ. In certain cases, a class name is added to the generated XML, which breaks deserialization. The most difficult problem for me to explain is that in production, a certain XML value will not generate an exception, while in dev, I will get an exception.

The badly serialized XML:

```
<company.events.twitter.InteractionReceivedFromTwitter4>
    <header>
        <id serialization="custom">
            <com.eaio.uuid.UUID>
                <long>4426172843343876581</long>
                <long>-7002731889965487449</long>
            </com.eaio.uuid.UUID>
        </id>
        <date>1433342326156</date>
        <data class="scala.collection.immutable.Map$EmptyMap$"/>
    </header>
    <!-- more data fields -->
</company.events.twitter.InteractionReceivedFromTwitter4>
```

This XML cannot be serialized, but *was* generated from XStream 1.4.8. If I edit the XML and remove the `<com.eaio.uuid.UUID>` and corresponding closing tags (just the tags) and leave the content, the XML will correctly deserialize.

I want to understand how and why this extra notation is added. The code I use to serialize and deserialize:

```
class XStreamSerializer extends Serializer {
    private val xstream = new XStream

    def serialize(x: AnyRef) = xstream.toXML(x).getBytes

    def deserialize(data: Array[Byte], contentType: String) = {
        if (contentType != serializationContentType)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only decode " + serializationContentType + ", received " + contentType)

        val res = xstream.fromXML(new ByteArrayInputStream(data))

        Option(res)
    }

    def serializationContentType = "application/xml;charset=utf-8"
}

case class MessageHeader( id: UUID,  date: Long,  data: Map[String, String])
case class InteractionReceivedFromTwitter4(header: MessageHeader,
                                           correlationId: UUID,
                                           interaction: InteractionMessage,
                                           persona: InteractionPersona)
```

In development, I never see that extra class mention. I can "fix" this by removing the strings "" and the close tag, but I want to understand.

I don't actually care what data format is exchanged on-the-wire. Whether the class name is there or not doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to track down the issue. I use Scala 2.9.0.1 on the deserialization side, and Scala 2.11.4 on the serializing side. The Java objects that Scala 2.11 generates are structurally different than the Scala 2.9.0.1 Java objects, which should explain the difference.

I also tracked down a difference in the UUID library I was using, 3.4 on the deserialization side, 3.2 on the serialization one.